# Regd. type conversion

Tags: type-conversion

I'm trying to write a simple code to give the output of sum of a harmonic series of n terms. While I wrote and executed the code as follows

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
   sum = sum + (1/i);
```

I'm not able to get the desired output. The output is displayed for me as `sum = 1.000000` while the same peace of code is working if it is as follows:

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
   sum = sum + (1/(float)i);
```

actual output: `sum = 2.283334`

Can anyone please explain how the type conversion here is impacting the output?

Answer (score 0):

The computer thinks that (1/i) should be an integer. When 1 is divided by i the decimal part is dropped to get an integer value. Since 1/i results in 0.xxxx, when the decimal part is dropped you are left with 0. Changing i to a float tells it that the number should be a float. You could get a similar result by using `sum = sum + (1.0/i);` if you wanted to.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It was so helpful